# Connecting with dsn

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I have an application written in Classic ASP and VBScript. First it was developed for SQL Server 2000; I have upgraded this to SQL Server 2008. Previously I only need to define the DSN in the page like so:

```
DSN=""DSN="rrrr",UID="gggg"
```

But after upgrading to SQL Server 2008 it is not working. I need to define password attribute for this. (like this?)

```
  DSN="DSN="rrrr",UID="gggg,PWD=xxxx""
```

Do we need to provide a password attribute or am I missing something?

Comment: THis site has always helped me: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008/

Comment: (1) I've never seen quoted values in a DSN string. Have you tried `DSN="DSN=rrrr,UID=gggg"`? (2) Silly question perhaps, but did the DSN survive the upgrade process? I.e. is the name you're using still an available, defined data source name?

Comment: @Martha-man dont concentrate on quotes..I just didnot wanted to copy paste the code.yes it is available .

Comment: The DSN-less connectionstring from the link posted by @Andrew should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

You have quite a few different options to change your connection string to work with SQL Server 2008.  If you are setting Trusted_Connection to true, then the password argument isn't used.  You might have set up a 2008 INSTANCE, in which case, you need to use Server\Instance.  It might be that simple.

From ConnectionStrings.com:

**Standard Security**

Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;
Password=myPassword;

**Trusted Connection**
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;

**Connection to a SQL Server instance**
Server=myServerName\myInstanceName;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;
Password=myPassword;

**Connect via an IP address**
Data Source=190.190.200.100,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;
Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;